# Access data created using Btrieve, stored in .DBK files

Tags: legacy, recovery, dbase, btrieve

I asked a question here a while back and using the answers, made some head way in figuring out how my DOS based legacy software works.

My problem: The software uses Btrieve to read/store data in .dbk files. I know this because the DDF files reference these dbk files. I found a number of ways to open btrieve data but only if they are stored in .btr files.

Anyone has any hints? I've spent considerable amount of time digging through resources but to no avail. All I need right now is to see the data stored in the dbk files in a readable format.

Answer (score 0):

If your DDFs reference .DBK files, you should, using a version of Btrieve / Pervasive that supports it, be able to use ODBC to read the data. 
Create the ODBC DSN pointing to your DDFs and Data Files. 
Once created, use your favorite export tool to export the data to your favorite format.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to find a program called Btrieve Commander that does exactly what I needed.